# AttachedProperty EventHandling and Memory Leaks

Tags: wpf, silverlight, events, memory-leaks, attached-properties

I am using an attached property which when set to true will start listening to an event. The problem is, I am not understanding how to add the remove handlers.

For example, I need to select all text of a textbox when it receives focus, only using attached properties. Once, the attached property is set to true, I start listening to the GotFocus event and I am providing the needed functionality. But if you observe carefully, this attached property is never reset for me to remove these handlers and this will typically cause a memory leak at some point of time.

How do I avoid this?

I am using this functionality in Silverlight 5, so I expect it to work in Silverlight and not just limited to WPF.

Comment: Show youtr code on GotFocus where do you subscribe

Comment: @lll I use it in the PropertyChangedCallBack, so that when it is set to true, I can then attach the eventhandler

Comment: Show your full code, on the words we can not say exactly.

Comment: Set the property to false and when false then remove the handler. Attached property becomes part of the control. When control removed the attached property will be removed too. Except static handler will stay because its static. You could create a anonymous handler that deletes itself when needed. Its called weak event.